# Dynamic linq: passing entire query as string

Tags: linq

Looking at Dynamic Linq, it's possible to use strings to define the key parts of the query.  My question is, is it possible to pass the entire query in as a string?

ie: var foo = "from..."

Comment: you got the answer, is it helpfull

Comment: Hi Pranay, passing SQL strings wasn't my objective but thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ stands for "Language INtegrated Queries" - it's compiled with the rest of the code, not parsed on the run. You can use [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile your query on the run - but you will have to know in advance what local objects you want to send to the query.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the closest answer though I'm not sure how I would do this.

Comment: Well, that really depends on what you want to do. Here is a little tutorial on how to use CSharpCodeProvider: http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/02/treating-c-like-a-scripting-language/. Basically you need to compile a class that contains a static method that performs the LINQ query you want. And than invoke that method. I assume you are not LINQing to SQL, so if you're LINQing to XML, you simply send the XML document to that method, but if you are LINQing to other data structures, you need to plan exactly which objects you want to send to that method.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in dynamic LINQ -- dynamic LINQ only replaces specific pieces of the query.  You can use [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) on the data context in LINQ to SQL or [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) on a `DbSet<T>`, though, to execute specific SQL commands.